# Error in cudaGetDeviceProperties

Tags: cuda

I am trying to get the memory bus bandwidth of my device using the following code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
  int nDevices;

  cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);
  for (int i = 0; i < nDevices; i++) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);
    printf("Device Number: %d\n", i);
    printf("  Device name: %s\n", prop.name);
    printf("  Memory Clock Rate (KHz): %d\n",
           prop.memoryClockRate);
    printf("  Memory Bus Width (bits): %d\n",
           prop.memoryBusWidth);
    printf("  Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): %f\n\n",
           2.0*prop.memoryClockRate*(prop.memoryBusWidth/8)/1.0e6);
  }
}
```

And I am getting this error:

```
bandwidth.cu(13): error: class "cudaDeviceProp" has no member "memoryClockRate"

bandwidth.cu(15): error: class "cudaDeviceProp" has no member "memoryBusWidth"

bandwidth.cu(17): error: class "cudaDeviceProp" has no member "memoryClockRate"

bandwidth.cu(17): error: class "cudaDeviceProp" has no member "memoryBusWidth"

4 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000003c4_00000000-4_bandwidth.cpp1.ii".
make: *** [hello.cu_o] Error 2
```

Can Someone please help? I am using a **Tesla T10 Processor** GPU and **CUDA 3.2**.

Comment: Which version of CUDA are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [CUDA 3.2 documentation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/html/) online, and you will see that the [device properties](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/html/structcudaDeviceProp.html) were different back then. Either upgrade to CUDA 5.0 or adapt your code to CUDA 3.2.

If you decide to stick with CUDA 3.2, have a look at the SDK examples, especially `bandwidthTest.cu` which shows how it used to be done.

Comment: Then how do I calculate the peak memory bandwidth in CUDA 3.2..??

Comment: Did you check the examples of the SDK? There is a `bandwidthTest.cu` file which shows how it used to be done.